# How to save background color on close

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm doing an android game with Xamarin Forms and in this game you can choose if the theme is dark or light. What I did is creating staticressources (colors) in App.xmal.

```
<Application.Resources>

    <Color x:Key="PrincipalColor" >#181818</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrincipalColorInvert" >#ffffff</Color>

</Application.Resources>
```

But when the user changes the theme (the staticressources color) and quit the game it doesn't save his preferences. I heard about "App.Current.Properties["Id"] = ..." but I can't figure it out. If someone know how to do i'll be happy to know.
Thank you.

Comment: The app is compiled, that means it can't be "changed" anymore, but you can create a file (e.g. UserConf.xml) where it is written which theme he had saved/selected, and when the app is started, the app can read the file of what he had selected the last time

Comment: And how can the file be read ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to save the settings. So you can save them in a SQLite database, in XML format, in Json format or simply in a single file (but it is not so "good/nice").

Comment: I suppose that the simplest is the xml files because I already use sql database but it's quite difficult for now.

Comment: So the simplest thing would be to create a file and just write something in it, would just not be the nicest way.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/general/store-custom-information-config-file

here, I even found a version that is specially adapted for such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android

Save a color in `Resources` , in the example with a Button set a color Green or Red .

In MainPage.xaml at the top

```
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource defaultBackgroundColor}"
```

Then the Buttons

```
  <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Green" />

    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" Text="Red" />
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs  `using Xamarin.Essentials;`

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.Resources["defaultButtonBackgroundColor"] = Preferences.Get("defaultButtonBackgroundColor", "Blue");
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("BackgroundColor", "Green");
        App.Current.Resources["defaultBackgroundColor"] = Preferences.Get("BackgroundColor", "Blue");
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("BackgroundColor", "Red");
        App.Current.Resources["defaultBackgroundColor"] = Preferences.Get("BackgroundColor", "Blue");
    }
```

Also use it for change TextColor of a Button etc , PricipalColor for example.

`StaticResource` is set and `DynamicResource` you can change

App.xaml.cs

```
    <Application.Resources>

    <Color x:Key="PrincipalColor" >#181818</Color>

</Application.Resources>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.Resources["defaultButtonBackgroundColor"] = Preferences.Get("defaultButtonBackgroundColor", "Blue");
        App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColor"] = Preferences.Get("PrincipalColor", "#181818");
    }
```

Change and PrincipalColor to White or any other color with Button.

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("PrincipalColor", "White");
        App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColor"] = Preferences.Get("PrincipalColor", "#181818");
    }
```

MainPage.xaml in the first Button is `Static` and the 2e `Dynamic` changes TextColor

```
<Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Green" TextColor="{StaticResource PrincipalColor}" />

    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" Text="Red" TextColor="{DynamicResource PrincipalColor}" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this, but I did exactly the same as you and I have this error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I think I'm going to try on a new project

Comment: I put it on Github for download as small Example to compare with yours .https://github.com/borisoprit/BackgroundStackO

Comment: I update my Answer , made example with PrincipalColor used Static and Dynamic . Static is set and Dynamic you can change the Color and save it . For use in Button , Label etc